# Having some trouble getting service running with Docker and Terraform

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, terraform, spring-boot

I'm very new to DevOps but I'm trying to learn some of it a bit.  I'm working with Terraform, trying to get a service to run on AWS using Fargate and Docker.  I've successfully set up my ECR repositories, and I walked through [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bradford_hamilton/deploying-containers-on-amazons-ecs-using-fargate-and-terraform-part-2-2e6f6a3a957f) on getting a service set up in Fargate.  However, I'm having a bit of a problem.  When I walked through the tutorial, everything worked more or less fine (there were some small issues but it was mostly pilot error), but when I tried to deploy my own application everything kind of exploded, and I can't figure out why.

- The error I'm getting is 502 Bad Gateway.
- The application is a Java Spring application with embedded Tomcat.  I haven't changed any run configurations from the default Spring config.
- I am able to build and Dockerize my application locally and run it through Docker on my local machine and everything works fine.
- The only changes from the tutorial code (linked above) that I made was changing the Docker image and changing the app_port from 3000 to 8080 (I also enabled Access Logging and added an S3 bucket for that purpose)
- The application has some auth security enabled, and when I try to hit the LB I get a login screen, so I know at least my Docker image is being pulled correctly
- One of the errors in the task logs of my ECS instances says something about failing a health check, although I'm not able to figure out anything more than that.

To be honest I'm a total newbie at DevOps anything so I have no idea what I'm doing.  Can anyone point me in some direction to help me get started?

Comment: Do you have any logs from your service?

Comment: Based on the logs it looks like the application successfully started using Spring (it gives all the standard Spring output all the way to where it says "Started APP_NAME", and then it just exits.  No error, no exception, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like, because the application has security enabled, the health check was not able to hit the / endpoint and the health check was failing.  When I removed the health check block I was able to access the application.  I'll add a globally-open health check endpoint and that should fix the problem I think.